# jQuery Frame Animation plugin doesn't work in FireFox 4.0

Tags: jquery, animation, frame

http://demo.dev.bitami.com/jQuery/frameanimation/demo.html

This doesn't work in FF 4.0

I get:

> Warning: Error in parsing value for
>   'background-position'.  Declaration
>   dropped. Source File:

Please let me know if you can open it and how to fix it if it's to be fixable.

Thanks

Edit:

It seems like firefox doesn't like [space] as value in the position attribute:

```
obj.css("backgroundPosition", "0px " + offset + "px");
```

What can i replace it with or escape it perhaps?

Comment: I'm not getting an error in FF 4.0 on that page, however the animations are not working either. But I doubt it's because of the space, because that's the correct syntax. To which file and line does the error point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with 
`obj.css("backgroundPosition", "0px " + offset + "px");`

It has to be:
 `obj.css('background-position', ('0px ' + offset + 'px'));` in order to work in Firefox 4

I have posted the whole code here (with some other minor changes):

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-frame-animation-plugin-and-firefox-4